# How is the amqp-template optional for an amqp outbound channel adapter

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp

As I was looking through the documentation on spring integration's outbound channel adapter I saw that the amqp-template was an optional field. I also noticed that the exchange name and routing key appear on both the Rabbit Template and the outbound channel adapter.

If I did not provide an amqp-template what would the adapter use for the connection factory.

AND

If I specified 1 set of properties in the rabbit template and another in the outbound channel adapter and then gave the outbound channel adapter the rabbit template, which properties would be used? (Not that I would do that I am just curious which component gets their properties used over the other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I did not provide an amqp-template what would the adapter use for the connection factory.

It requires one from the context with the bean name `amqpTemplate` (`AmqpOutboundChannelAdapterParser`):

```
String amqpTemplateRef = element.getAttribute("amqp-template");
if (!StringUtils.hasText(amqpTemplateRef)) {
    amqpTemplateRef = "amqpTemplate";
```

Properties like `exchange` and `routingKey` are used for each `message`(`AmqpOutboundEndpoint`):

```
this.amqpTemplate.convertAndSend(exchangeName, routingKey, requestMessage.getPayload(),
```

The `ConfirmCallback` and `ReturnCallback` are configured for that `AmqpTemplate` from the `AmqpOutboundEndpoint`. However in this case you can't use shared bean and have to provide the separate one.

All other `RabbitTemplate` specific options must be provided on that bean definition. And `<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter>` doesn't have them.

Comment: Right; with the template, the exchange and RK are the defaults to be used for the simple method calls; the adapter uses the method calls that take a (dynamic) exchange and RK, allowing a single adapter to be used to send messages to different exchanges/queues. You can, of course, share the template with other components, which are free to use the simple send methods.

Comment: Sorry, still a bit confused. I have a simple application that takes in messages and sends them to a header-enricher that puts a "RoutingKey" header on it. Then I have an outbound-channel-adapter with a routing-key-expression="headers['RoutingKey']" and the exchange declared on that adapter (e.exchange.1). I also have a rabbit template (id="rabbitTemplate) which also has an exchange(e.exchange.2) specified. If I set the template="rabbitTemplate" on the outbound channel adapter which exchange is is going to use to send the message?

Comment: I just read through the AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java on Github and it appears that it ignores the pre-defined exchange and routing key settings on the template and uses the one defined on the int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter (as far as I can tell).